# How to verify and decode a jwt oauth token in java?

Tags: java, oauth, jwt

I get a JWT token from google, but I can't find out how to verify and decode this.

I am trying to use the library com.auth0.jwt.JWT, and I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServerFailException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    System.out.println("Starting now");

    String publicKey="885016258715-j50dd8tkkee3ttqaqer14s4vd9fvbtbd.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String token="eyJhbGciOiJSUz..."
    
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey=null; // This should be null, because we don't need the private key to decode the token.
    RSAPublicKey pubKey=How do I convert My string public key to a RSAPublicKey.
    
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(pubKey, privateKey);
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
            .withIssuer("auth0")
            .build();

    DecodedJWT decodedJWT=verifier.verify(token);
    Map<String, Claim> claims = decodedJWT.getClaims();
    System.out.println(claims);
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

But the probelm is how I get the RSAPublicKey from the public key string, I got from google. Or Is there a fundamental better way to do this? (A different library).

Comment: From memory, the most I remember giving the auth0 library was a secret so that it could verify the JWT. JWTs are not encrypted as such, they are "signed/encoded" so that any tampering is apparent, you should never ever put anything confidential in a JWT. You should be able to go to jwt.io paste your JWT in and see its claims, these should match the map of claims you get be calling .getClaims. I found the Auth0 documentation and tutorials to be quite good.

Comment: You may find this tutorial helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/java-auth0-jwt Section 2.3 points out that a token signed with a public/private key pair certifies that token originated from the party holding the private key, so in your case you should be able to verify the key pair, and know the token is from Google.

Comment: @Gawin I can't use that tutorial. 2.3 just say that the signature "Can be verified", but not how this is done. And the code example use HMAC256, but I need a RSA because that is what the token from google use.

Comment: Section 3.2 and 3.4 shows how to verify the token. It shows how to do it for HMAC, to do the same for RSA would be `Algorithm.RSA256` or which RSA bit length you are using. You will need to check the docs on how to construct the appropriate key object to pass to the `RSAnnn` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to convert that string to an RSA public key. What you usually do in this scenario is to call a JWKS endpoint exposed by Google, where you would have the key in a format similar to this:

```json
{
    "kty":"RSA",
    "kid":"2091097665",
    "use":"sig",
    "alg":"RS256",
    "n":"nuR5CoNGpJCFRVDQyitG_0oX8d_O1f4QWT5M_ZHoS_XXjJ2ZGCDwukArnyBfEiXmzS4sEITFHmR6eS_y4fIDjkQxlH8wrhEL8enPe6Qs2qNphACydaDyvBurSEuH73JqU7hiXvge6DMONwlv0zhzqYOG4_SFiH8Qxk4gewmTFmw-ib5u-yuXTAKckYIRpQAnLTDAm1HK-MUQWZTALi1QVcpjh-afsGR42GlgWNcGip7UuPv_4YoIVj0G-6HTpdCj1SrV1dkxGPOYxFeJ96-9EWRJ6mJt0r1J9u-A1Yp9Le_FPdR6nhN7N4CzZYoG8lwdXXPeDmV8LD8PHW-SpoyPzw",
    "e":"AQAB",
    "x5t":"OjVeMZFPa9LLP0pyd4Z_dN5-Iis"
}
```

Alternatively, you could get the key in a PEM format, where it would look something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyemE1zfNxurz773Igh8r
cbXaqeIiKcoOYkcKyx5CYb01A69mDkOD6L6dIva9gAI2abyp3PCNKCCsCECgxAnn
eAzzNad+I5y02SdxWo17yR1/KmkpSAB7bbqwSeG3gJ3aUfgSIWr47kama3R2epm+
50G6zFrI8GK5Sy5J1qVXbdsMXLMWiEjCMQv5BUp/e4k/nLnyOvUkALGaqIc7BdJb
LznNehxLv2xysS5T0gjQ0yknr/QaSqV6rZpCv08uIuO+uC6jKyZUUSxcW5eokco6
LnoLkTBwnhg8ztERp1QU3RVWBUxAgs+xhNsarySrpoePOEpoaLSIAwLT8xAQLVOo
xwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Once you have the key in one of these formats, it should be straightforward to import it to the library. (It might be event that the constructor method accepts one of these formats.)

Comment: Turns out I had misunderstod how things worked. The token is not sigend by my private key, but by googles public key. So I don't really need to use my private key for anything which explains why there we no examples using the private key to decode jwt tokens.